# Git not displaying branches other than master

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have just cloned a repository which worked and all the files I am expecting to see from my master branch are there. However, the repository also has another branch, `experiment`. When I run `git branch`, it is not displayed, even after I run `git fetch --all`. In my repo in the cloud (Visual Studio Team Services, was Visual Studio Online) I can see it, just not locally. What do I need to do to check this branch out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git branch` only shows your local branches. Use `git branch -a` to show all branches. Your missing branch should be displayed then.

Use `git checkout experiment`to create a local from the remote branch and check it out. After that a simple `git branch`should also show a local branch `experiment`